# Include db entry in session data when logging user in (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, session-variables

What I'd like to do is on validating a CI user, when setting their session data, pull some data from a field set in the db.

At the moment I have this within my controller;

```
function validate()
{
    $query = $this->model_auth->validate();

        if ($query) // if the user's credentials validated 
        {
            $data = array(
                'username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in'  => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('dashboard/');
        } else {
            $data['error'] = 'Invalid User Id and Password combination';
            $this->load->view('view_login',$data);
        }

}
```

**and this is my model**

```
function validate() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1) { return TRUE; } 

    }//validate
```

What I'd like to do is set something like this;

```
$data = array(
                'username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
                'user_level'    => $ThisIsSomethingWithinTheDB,
                'is_logged_in'  => TRUE
            );
```

Within my controller, with $ThisIsSomethingWithinTheDB relating to the relevant entry within the db under the user_level column.

I'm currently still very much learning as I go so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help both,

I was able to achieve this as follows;

**model;**

```
function validate() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return $query;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }


    }
```

**Controller;**

```
function validate()
{
    $query = $this->model_auth->validate();

        if ($query) // if the user's credentials validated 

        {
        $user_data = $query->row();
        $data = array(
            'username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
            'user_level'    => $user_data->user_level,
            'is_logged_in'  => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('dashboard/'); 
        } else {
        $data['error'] = 'Invalid User Id and Password combination';
        $this->load->view('view_login',$data);
        }

}
```

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set something equal to something from your database you're going to have to retrieve it first.

I'm not too familiar going with CI's ActiveRecord as I prefer to use Laravel and Eloquent but from what I can tell looking at the docs:

`$this->db->get('users')`

... would be equivalent to:

`SELECT * FROM users`

and if that's the case, you should be able to set:

`$data['user_level'] = $ThisIsSomethingWithinTheDB`

or

`$this->session->set_userdata('user_level') = $ThisIsSomethingWithinTheDB`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your validate() function, to return the DB results.

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now, you can access the DB results, like this in your controller...

```
if ($query)
{
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'user_level' => $query->user_level, // This is "user_level" row from your DB
        'is_logged_in' => true
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Craig,

Thanks for your help, I seem to be getting the follow error now Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/auth.php

Comment: I've checked the db and the entry is not set however I am logged in :/

Comment: You will be logged in, because the 'is_logged_in' is true. I will modify the function above...

Comment: I have modified the validation function for your model above. If that doesn't work, try and var_dump the $query variable, and see if the results are been returned from the model.

Comment: Thanks again Craig, appears all that is being returned is bool(true) 

I'm thinking I may have to rewrite my approach to within the validate function and try a different angle :/